# how to increment variable by 0.5 in using for loop?

Tags: tcl

```
for {set i 0} {$i < 5} {incr i} {
    puts "I inside first loop: $i"
}
```

Is it possible to increment `i` by  .5 instead of 1 ?

Now the above code is providing below output:

- i inside first loop: 0
- i inside first loop: 1
- i inside first loop: 2
- i inside first loop: 3
- i inside first loop: 4

but I need something like this:

- I inside first loop: 0
- I inside first loop: .5
- I inside first loop: 1

... so on

Answer (score 3):

By default, [`incr`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/incr.htm) increments by 1 unit when no specific number is mentioned.

```
incr i 2
```

will increment `i` by 2 on each iteration.

```
incr i -1
```

will decrement `i` by 1 on each iteration.

You can thus change the number to be whatever you need it to be.

The only problem is that you can only increment by an integer. So you'll have to use something else for the 0.5. You can use `expr` perhaps?

```
for {set i 0} {$i < 5} {set i [expr {$i+0.5}]} {
    puts "I inside first loop: $i"
}
```

EDIT: Actually, Donal's answer is better since it doesn't have the rounding errors :)

Comment: How to increment by 0.5?

Answer (score 3):

Tcl's `incr` command only handles integer values. The recommended way of getting a loop value that steps by some fractional value is to use a integer loop counter and then compute the fractional value from it:

```
for {set i_int 0} {$i_int < 5} {incr i_int} {
    set i [expr {$i_int * 0.5}]
    puts "I inside first loop: $i"
}
```

This is important when the fractional step is not a simple multiple of a power of two; while `0.5` can be represented exactly in binary floating point arithmetic (it's 2<sup>-1</sup> after all) `0.1` can't (just as <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub> can't be written exactly in a finite number of decimal places).